# Express api res.jsonp returns double callback

Tags: node.js, express, jsonp

I have an Express server running at port 8080 with this route

```
app.get('/api', function (req, res) {
  res.jsonp('user API is running');
});
```

I open a browser window to

```
http://ec2-54-226-27-72.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/api?callback=hello
```

The response in the browser is

```
hello && hello("user API is running");
```

Why are there 2 hellos?  Is this a proper JSONP response from Express and will it be processed correctly by a client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's the proper format.  The purpose of the first hello is to make sure that the function hello exists on the client before trying to call it (an error would occur if the function did not exist).

There's a little bit of info about this in the preview chapter of the express book [here](http://expressjs-book.com/).  I just read it the other day.

Comment: Thanks.  Sorry to persist but is JSON_CALLBACK a special callback name that returns data to the standard success or error callbacks on the client?  That is working for me.

Comment: From the GET request parameter callback=json_callback? You could rename json_callback to anything you like--it's the function that will be called on the client when the function returns, as you did with your hello callback.  I'm afraid I don't know much more than that about JSONP.